# FTP Permissions read but not write

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

I made a personal FTP server on an old laptop but when I connect I can only read/download no upload. How do I change this? Thanks for the help in advance I am use vsftpd

Comment: Do you get permission denied?Without further details it would be difficult to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Yes Permissions denied

Answer (score 21):

- You will have to edit  the `vsftpd.conf` settings file, located at `/etc/ with an editor of you choice, for example:

`sudo vim /etc/vsftpd.conf`

- In the settings file look for the line `write_enable=YES` which will be probably commented out `#write_enable=YES`, uncomment it removing the `#` from the front and save the file.
- Finally restart the vsftpd service using:

`sudo service vsftpd restart`

*Note that:*

*You will have to provide your password when you use `sudo`.*
*Also, the service was originally listed in this answer as ftpd which may work on some machines instead of vsftpd*

Comment: Hi there, I have uncomment write_enable=YES but it doesnt work. It says could not create file

Comment: This is part of the answer but not enough. I'm having the same issue and this doesn't resolve it. I think you need to create a user on the server and give them permissions but I'm still reading up. Will update if I find the solution.

Comment: It did work for me.

Comment: I whink `write_enable=YES` doesn't work for `chroot`enabled setup. In this case you need to use `allow_writeable_chroot=YES` which is insecure and undocumented.
For the FTP user to have it's own folder with write permission I guess the only way it to use virtual users....I'm still lookiing for a good guide for this myself.